# ItemizedOverlay that has more fields

Tags: java, android, overlay, parcelable

As you know an overlay item has only title, message and drawable image.

I want to create a customize item that has for example also the folowing fields: ID,street,city,country.

After OnTap is being invoked I want to display that info in a listview, so after you tap on the item there comes a list with the ID,street,city and country of the specified item.

So, as I understand, I have to create another activity who will display that list, that means that I have to send the data to the listActivity by Parceling the itemizedoverlay class.

I'm having an hard time thinking how to do it, since when I create that constructor:

```
public MyItemizedOverlay(Parcel source){
     /*
      * Reconstruct from the Parcel
      */
     Log.d("MyTag", "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");

     ID = source.readInt();
     imagePath = source.readInt();
     distance = source.readFloat();
```

}

I'm getting the following error(meanning that I must call the base constructor):

> Implicit super constructor ItemizedOverlay() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

**Conclusion:** There's a big chance that there's another solution for this, I'm sure that people have faced that situation already, so I'll be gladly like to hear your solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two constructors in the following manner, this method works for me:

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
  super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, String ID, String city, String country) {
  super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
  #do something with the ID, city, country. Possibly store them in instance variables
}
```

Comment: You know what it does when I call the base constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by the base constructor? Are you referring to the first or the second constructor?